# Compiling in Flashdevelop OpenFL takes 31 minutes

Tags: c++, haxe, flashdevelop, openfl

I'm new to Haxe and I think I've messed something up.

If I open up a new OpenFL project in Flashdevelop and immediately compile it with windows(c++) as my target, the initial compilation takes about 31 minutes. Most of that time is spent processing the "src/**resources**.cpp" file.

Subsequent compilations of the empty project take about 10 seconds.

For reference compiling to either flash or html takes about 3-5 seconds.

My CPU is an intel i5 3.3GHz and the project is being compiled on a standard HDD.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Many projects depending on libraries you can switch to using NME, using the same project, so as a good test it might be worth checking the compile times to see if it's a specific OpenFL bug or if NME compile is also slow then it's likely a more hxcpp related bug.  I suggest you submit an issue to the OpenFL github unless you can be sure it's Haxe compiler issue.  Sorry not to be of more help.

Comment: Good thing is you can also use a different target to test/debug with, the result should be the same across targets! Welcome to Haxe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Visual Studio you use?
There is [issue with Visual Studio Express 2010](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues/1583)

Comment: That is more a comment than  an answer

Comment: If he use VSE 2010 there was answer - update to later version

Comment: Thank you so much, VSE2010 was the problem. Installed VS2013 and my initial compile time went down to 2 min.